# how to extract the part of filename with extension(like solution.txt-->sol.txt)?

Tags: shell, filenames

I need to extract part of filename with extension (i.e. `solution.txt` -> `sol.txt`).

Answer (score 3):

Using parameter expansion:

```
$ file="solution.txt"
$ echo "${file:0:3}.${file##*.}"
sol.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Done by using sed and python

```
echo "solution.txt" |sed "s/\(...\)\([a-z]\{5\}\)\(....\)/\1\3/g"
```

output

```
sol.txt
```

---

Using Python

```
 a="solution.txt"
print a[0:3] + a[-4:]
```

output

```
sol.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way, by splitting the filename into components and then rebuilding it to desired form:

```
#!/bin/sh
origname="$1"
# directory = everything from "origname" except the part after the last /
directory="${origname%/*}"
if [ "$origname" = "$directory" ]; then
    # there was no directories in the original name at all
    directory="."
fi
# to get the filename, remove everything up to the last /
filename="${origname##*/}"
# to get the extension, remove everything up to the last .
extension="${origname##*.}"

# take first 3 characters of original filename as a new name
newname="$(echo "$filename" | cut -c 1-3)"

# output the result
echo "${directory}/${newname}.${extension}"
```

This is longer, but hopefully easier to understand and modify to suit the use case.

Comment: `\"$filename\"` - what are those backslashes for?

Comment: That  part of the command line goes through the parser twice: once for the line itself, another for the `$( ... )` construct. The double quotes need to be still there for the second round.

Comment: Huh? Each `$()` creates a new quoting context, so you can nest them easily: `echo "$(echo "$var" "$(echo "a   b")")"`. I don't think `\"` will do what you expect it to do :)

Comment: You're right. I blame ENOCOFFEE...